# Is 'per' necessary in the expression "viaggerei per il mondo"?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following expressions is correct?

> Viaggerei il mondo

or

> Viaggerei per il mondo

I'm just wondering as to whether the *per* is necessary.

Comment: *Viaggiare* is not transitive.

Comment: @DaG I think you could expand your comment into an answer

Comment: "Per" is absolutely necessary, without "per" the sentence has no sense.

Comment: @Andy7229082: Welcome to Italian.SE! An answer should be something more than a mere statement like yours. Can you complete it, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Viaggiare is an action verb but it is not transitive, which means that you cannot use it with a direct object.
So the expression

> Viaggerei il mondo

is not correct.
The preposition *per* is not strictly necessary, you can use whatever type of complement is appropriate, for instance you can say

> Viaggerei attraverso ogni continente

Comment: Or also *viaggerei in lungo e in largo*.